# How many tables will be there in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento

I just started using Magento with 1500 products and I saw the DB size is about 150MB and when I looked at the tables, the count is 250 tables.

Is it normal?

Should I worry about anything?

I host this on EC2 micro instance.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry if I were you. Many systems (Oracle's EBS e-business suite) have gazillions (a techical term meaning a large [number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers)) of tables, most of which will never be used by many customers. Any major e-commerce/ERP/ERM system will be like this. You'll find that you'll be spending 85% of your time working with just a few modules which are core to your own business - and that's as it should be.

Just as a matter of interest, what prompted you to go with Magento? You business speciality? Are you going commerical or Open Source? Did you consider other solutions Sugar CRM/Adiempere/Apache OfBiz?

Comment: Magento uses EAV and one of the problems is the gazillion tables.